# What's the difference between "abort" and "terminate-thread" in emacs?

Tags: emacs, lisp, terminate, abort

When I use emacs, I often meet some errors in my code.

When there are some errors in my code, emacs ask me whether I want to "abort" or "terminate-thread".

I want to know what the difference is between "abort" and "terminate-thread" in emacs.
Which one should I choose that will be better?

[image]

Comment: are you calling any external processes?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this question comes from Emacs.  So please give us more information (OS in which you run Emacs, which processes you might be running within Emacs, what kind of error happens, where is the actual question displayed (within Emacs's minibuffer, or some popup dialog), ...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SLIME?

In that case, "abort" will just stop your program, whereas "terminate-thread" will also kill the Lisp thread that SLIME is talking to.

Comment: I added a picture in my question. First, I use "terminate-thread". Then I use "abort". Here is the picture show on my computer. But I cannot see the difference.

Comment: If you cause another error after "terminate-thread", you will see that the memory address identifying the thread (which is displayed in the "terminate-thread" option) has changed. This is because SLIME has killed the previous REPL thread and made your Lisp implementation start a new one.

Comment: In my case, after using "terminate-thread", why it didn't show error when started a new one? or what is the case "terminate-thread" will cause another error? Thank you.